# "The PayPal iOS SDK is currently available in the US", what it specifically mean?

Tags: ios, paypal

From current PayPal developer iOS SDK [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/):

> The PayPal iOS SDK is currently available in the US, with more
>   country support coming soon.

This mean receiving payment company must be in the United States and а payer may pay anywhere, or payer is also required to be in US?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You answered your own question.
```

> PayPal is replacing the Mobile Payments Libraries (MPL) with the
>   PayPal iOS SDK. The PayPal iOS SDK is currently available in the US,
>   with more country support coming soon. **US developers should upgrade
>   now for more features and a better mobile experience. Non-US
>   developers, you can continue to use MPL for the time being.**

**This mean receiving payment company must be in the United States and а payer may pay anywhere**